# Does singly linked list have to be defined recursively?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I understand how to define a singly linked list recursively in java:

```
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
}
```

My question is: Does singly linked list have to be defined recursively?

Comment: can you elaborate this? `defined recursively`

Comment: `singly linked list` is a list where each item has a pointer to next one. It can be defined any way you want.

Comment: @tym32167  when I define class ListNode, the class ListNode is used to define itself. Could you come up with a way to define the class directly?

Comment: You can use `Object next;` and store whenever you want in it. You can use `Map<Integer, ListNode>` and have `int next;` field as part of it. You can use array `int[] items` where `item[i]` points to next item. You can use different implementations, depends of your needs.

Comment: @tym32167 thank you sooooo much! I'll dive into every point you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. Here is just one of the many ways you can implement a linked list non-recurisvely (implementations of methods not shown):

```
class LinkedList {
    private ListNode[] nodes;
    private int start;
    private int nextEmpty;
    
    private static class ListNode {
        private int val;
        private int next;
    }
}
```

Use an array to store the nodes. Each node has a value and a `next`. The `next` field stores the index of the next node in the array.

`start` indicates the index of the first node. `nextEmpty` indicates where the next node will be inserted (the next empty spot).

The methods like `add`, `remove`, `get` `size` and `insert` will make use of `start` and `nextEmpty`, and potentially set them. If you `remove` the first item for example, `start` will be set to the index of the next item, and `nextEmpty` will be set to the index of the removed item.

The array can also grow when needed, just like how `ArrayList` grows *its* internal array.